# Increment operator didn't work in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an array of question and answer id. I have to check those answers are matched with my database answer. so I try it this way:

```
var point = 0;
var wrong_answer = 0;

MnaUniqueData.forEach((element, array) => {

    models.Questions.findByPk(element.question_id).then(TheQuestion => {
    
        if(TheQuestion.answer === element.answer_no){
            return point++
        }else{
            wrong_answer++
        }

    })
});

console.log(point)
console.log(wrong_answer)
```

in the end, it returns me the initial value only...

Answer (score 0):

That happening 'cause de `console.log` is out of promise.
But what this means? Means the `console.log` will be executed before the `forEach` ends his execution.

Try this:

```
var point = 0;
var wrong_answer = 0;

await MnaUniqueData.forEach(async (element, array) => {

    await models.Questions.findByPk(element.question_id).then(TheQuestion => {
    
        if(TheQuestion.answer === element.answer_no){
            point++
        }else{
            wrong_answer++
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have been tried this way how you mentioned. It returned me the initial value only.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you realize I removed the `return` statement  inside the `if` condition?